# What I have to do when I need to encode the file to base64 but `ProgressEvent.target.result` is null or has `ArrayBuffer` type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, base64, arraybuffer

According to TypeScript types definitions, the type of `ProgressEvent.target.result` could be `string`, `ArrayBuffer` or `null`.
What I need is, the function which encodes the file to base64 which is type `string`.
But what I have to do when it is `null` or instance of `ArrayBuffer`?

```js
async function encodeFileToBase64(targetFile: File): Promise<string> {

  const fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.readAsDataURL(targetFile);

  return new Promise<string>((resolve: (encodedFile: string) => void, reject: (error: Error) => void): void => {

    fileReader.onload = (filedHasBeenReadEvent: ProgressEvent<FileReader>): void => {

      const fileReadingResult: string | ArrayBuffer | null | undefined = filedHasBeenReadEvent.target?.result;

      if (isEitherUndefinedOrNull(fileReadingResult)) {
        reject(new Error("Failed to encode the file."));
        return;
      }


      resolve(
        fileReadingResult instanceof ArrayBuffer ?
            String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(fileReadingResult)) :
            fileReadingResult
      );

    };

  });

}
```

The "Failed to encode the file." error has not enough details.

- What means `null`?
- Why has it occured?
- What is required to do to have the `string` type next time?

Same sub-question about `ArrayBuffer`.
Additionally, I have TypeScript error in

```
String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(fileReadingResult))
```

> S2345: Argument of type  Uint8Array  is not assignable to parameter of type  number[] 
> Type  Uint8Array  is missing the following properties from type  number[] :  pop, push, concat, shift , and  5  more.

Comment: Why not listen to the `FileReader.onerror` event to find out? You should be hooking a reject into that anyway and not the load I think. Also `Uint8Array` is not an `Array` I think (it's special), so assign it to an actual `Array` to solve your argument call issue? Like `[...new Uint8Array(result)]`

Comment: @somethinghere Thank you for the comment. Understood about `FileReader.onerror`. However, there are still the questions. I'll start the bounty.

Comment: Note that when calling `readAsDataURL` the `result` type is **never** an `ArrayBuffer`. The reason it has multiple options is because you can also do `readAsArrayBuffer`, and typescript can't tell which so the event has both types. If a `null` is in the `result` when loaded, something has gone wrong and you should have read that error with `onerror`.

Comment: Why do you even need it as base64 in the first place? there are better ways to handle raw files now days.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to use `event.target`, as `event.target` is the "a reference to the object onto which the event was dispatched", so it's just the `fileReader` itself
2. The type of `fileReader.result` depends on the operation you call over it.   Depending on the operation, FileReader can be one of:

```
const fr: FileReader = new FileReader();
//        ^^^^^^^^^^ required for asserts to work
interface FileReader {
    readAsArrayBuffer(blob: Blob): asserts this is XOR<{ result: ArrayBuffer }, { error: DOMException }, null>;
    readAsBinaryString(blob: Blob): asserts this is XOR<{ result: string }, { error: DOMException }, null>;
    readAsDataURL(blob: Blob): asserts this is XOR<{ result: dataUrl }, { error: DOMException }, null>;
    readAsText(blob: Blob): asserts this is XOR<{ result: string }, { error: DOMException }, null>;
}

type XOR<A, B, Miss = never> = Prettify<
    | A & Omit<{ [K in keyof B]?: Miss }, keyof A>
    | B & Omit<{ [K in keyof A]?: Miss }, keyof B>
>
type Prettify<T> = T extends T ? { [K in keyof T]: T[K] } : never
```

3. [The value is null if the reading is not yet complete or was unsuccessful.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result#value). So, as you have already awaited the `load` event, if means that `fileReader.error` has the error value.

Personally I would recommend a wrapper of the whole FileReader like https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tanker/file-reader or a typed variant of MDN example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target#example

```
const reader = (file: File) =>
    new Promise<dataUrl>((resolve, reject) => {
        const fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onload = () => resolve(fr.result as dataUrl);
        fr.onerror = (err) => reject(fr.err);
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
type dataUrl = string & { _?: 'dataUrl' } // branded for clearness
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'am sorry, but looks like something wrong with `onerror`. According TypeScript types definitions, it has signature `onerror: ((this: FileReader, ev: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) => any) | null;`.

Comment: Every event on `FileReader` seems to be a `ProgressEvent`, but the `error` propery is a `DOMException` - https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-error-event . Should the code use `reject(fr.error)` then?

Comment: > If package data threw an exception error:
Set fr’s error to error.
Fire a progress event called error at fr. --- so they are different things

Answer (score 1):

1. 'null' is a variable that is defined, but is missing the value
2. In practice, most of the 'null' values arise from human error during
   programming, and these two go together in most cases.
3. readAsDataUrl will always return you a 'string' type

[image]

4. The issue is String.fromCharCode expects an array of `number[]` as the argument. So you need to convert it from Uint8Array to normal array.

   String.fromCharCode.apply(null, [...new Uint8Array(fileReadingResult)])

Hope this helps you @TakeshiTokugawaYD!